# how to align button at the bottom of the screen in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I am using linearlayout as parent and inside it I have two child linearlayouts. I want to align the buttons in the last linearlayout to the bottom of the screen.The bottom margin of the buttons should match the main linearlayouts bottom margin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Reset" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know what's your problem, I took ur code and view it on eclipse and the Buttons is already aligned at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reduce the `textsize` of the button Text. Since it is not able to display text in one line the margin is getting distorted.

Here I have made textSize to `11dp` for each `buttontext` and the view is perfect for `NexusOne` size display

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textSize="11dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes this too worked for me. But I doubt will it work if the data in the id=parentlayout increase will the buttons get overlapped with the textviews/edittexts?

Comment: It will work since the main xml layout is a `LinearLayout`. The `buttons` in the lower linearlayout will simple stay there. Whatever you add in `id=parentlayout` it will get inside the `scrollview` I can show an example by adding some elements in `parentlayout` if you want.

Comment: please select this as answer. :)

Comment: Where can I select this as an answer.I dont find any link or tag. For vote up I need 15 reputations:(

Comment: Hey I marked.My images on the webpasge were blocked so I was not able to see the tick mark:)

Comment: I have obtained some dynamic data which is going into the LinearLayout with id parentlayout in the above code.Now I am not able to see the buttons.When data is less I can see the buttons available at the bottom.What could be the reason?ScrollView height is wrap_content still it is taking the whole screen

Comment: Add a super scroll layout.. which covers everything. So now, if you really need the xml to linear layout, you can add `scrollview` as parent layout to everything else (in this case, a scrollview (with linearlayout) and linearlayout) OR if you don't need xml to be `linearlayout` you can make have scrollview as main xml layout. Let me know if you have doubts in this.

Comment: Hey thanks did not see your message for a while. Instead of adding a super scroll layout I just added another parent linearlayout to the existing button linearlayout with its orientation vertical.So it became <parentlinearlayout> orientation vertical<child linearlayout> orientation horizontal and then the buttons </close child></close parent>

Answer (score 1):

try this using your parent as **RelativeLayout**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Reset" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have used relativelayouts with TableLayout inside it worked perfectly in the past.But now I want to get it working with LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you use `RelativeLayout` for this kind of requirements. Would work without hassle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/buttons"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Save" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Cancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Delete" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Reset" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/save"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/submit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cancel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/delete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Delete"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/reset"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Reset"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hey thanks this worked perfectly for me. But why should we use a tree of linearlayouts for buttons?Also please let me know if the list of data in android:id="@+id/parentlayout" increases will the text get overlapped with the buttons?